# Sonar, QAPlug, IntelliJ Integration - Multiple profiles?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I've set up a Sonar installation on our build server so that we can maintain reporting on our coding rules compliance, code coverage, etc.

What I want to do is maintain this Sonar installation as the main source of our checkStyle, findBugs and PMD rules. Sonar supports this by letting you modify the rules its using and export them. I can then import these rules to developer machines running IntelliJ Idea with the QAPlug plugin.

The problem is that I have to import profiles individually. Which means I will have to run QAPlug with the checkStyle profile, then then the PMD plugin, then the findBugs plugin. This is a few too many steps to expect developers to do all the time.

I can combine them within the plugin itself, so that it executes PMD, checkStyle and findBugs rules at the same time. But then the amount of steps to maintain the profile becomes too large. ie. Modify rule in Sonar, export 3 profiles, combine 3 profiles into one, distribute to developers.

Is there a better way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you can import into an already existing profile. So I just needed to import all 3 files into QAPlug, and now I have a combined profile.